# Django Caching when using @login_required

Tags: python, django, caching

I'm using the decorator @login_required to only show the pages when a user is authenticated. However, I noticed my DB (hosted on AWS) is a bit slow because of this request. Every time the user goes to a new page and the decorator @login_required is called, it makes a query to the DB. I would like to cache this, so that the it's not necessary to check all the time. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Upon looking further I see that the Time to first Byte (TTFB) is always one second, but for example when I'm using a local database, the TTFB is way less. What could be the reason for a high value of TTFB?
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668757/152016 and django-redis (https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

- Import this

  `from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page`
- Add this decorator `@cache_page(60 * 15)` above `@login_required` decorator

This technique is called [per-view cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Do you think the problem is related with caching the page? I mean, I don't see a difference in speed between my pages. Upon looking more, I found that the problem is something related with TTFB. The TTFB always take 1s.